# Null error from findByIdAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

So I have this API method:

```
router.delete('/circleAlertDelete/:id', function(req, res, next){
  User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).then(function(user){
    var userTemp = user;
    var alerts = user.circleAlerts;
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<alerts.length; i++){
      if(alerts._id == req.body.alertID){
        alerts.splice(i,1);
      }
    }
    userTemp.circleAlerts = alerts;
    console.log(req.params.id);
    User.findByIdAndUpdate({'_id': req.params.id}, userTemp, function(err, user){
      console.log("error:",err);
      res.send(user);
    });
  }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
});
```

I've also tried this to no avail:

```
{'_id': mongo.ObjectId(req.params.id)}
```

When run the id printed with `console.log(req.params.id);`is that of a user in the database.

But also printed is `error: null`.

Can't figure this out, Thanks Ed.

Comment: So how does it fail? Is there an error?

Comment: It goes through but it can't find the user and therefore doesn't update it.

Comment: You are not surrounding the `console.log('error:', err)` with an `if(err)` statement. That way, the error line is printed always. Even when there is no error.

Comment: Yep, no error... good point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing plain object with just the field you want to set to `findByIdAndUpdate`:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {circleAlerts: alerts}, function(err, user) {
```

Which effectively is turned into the following update operation:

```
$set: { circleAlerts: alerts }}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not specifying how to update the document, just passing the new object. Try with

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: req.params.id}, {$set: userTemp}, function(err, user){
   console.log("error:",err);
   res.send(user);
});
```

Comment: I think you would need to call `userTemp.toObject()`. Note also that this updates all fields in user document, not just `circleAlerts`.